# Duplicated level name when using datetime in Chicago Crime Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working through the EDA of Chicago crime data from:
https://www.kaggle.com/currie32/crimes-in-chicago/notebook

And I keep encountering the error of:
ValueError: Duplicated level name: "Date", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0.

When trying to run:

```
hour_by_week     = crimes.pivot_table(values='ID', index=crimes.index.hour, columns=crimes.index.weekday_name, aggfunc=np.size).fillna(0)
hour_by_week     = hour_by_week[days].T # just reorder columns according to the the order of days
dayofweek_by_location = crimes.pivot_table(values='ID', index='Location Description', columns=crimes.index.dayofweek, aggfunc=np.size).fillna(0)
dayofweek_by_type = crimes.pivot_table(values='ID', index='Primary Type', columns=crimes.index.dayofweek, aggfunc=np.size).fillna(0)
location_by_type  = crimes.pivot_table(values='ID', index='Location Description', columns='Primary Type', aggfunc=np.size).fillna(0)
```

When you search this error it looks like an old pandas issue that was fixed by
crimes.groupby([crimes.Date.dt.month.rename('month'),crimes.Date.dt.day.rename('day')]).sum()

However if you try to run the code now with or without this block, you still get previous error listed.